Extension of field homomorphisms doubt
I have a doubt in the proof of the following theorem:
"Let $K$ be a perfect field. Given $\alpha \in \overline{K}$, with $[K(\alpha) : K] = n$, for any $\varphi : K \hookrightarrow \overline{K}$ immersion, there exist exactly $n$ extensions of $\varphi$ to an immersion from $K(\alpha)$ to $\overline{K}$"
The proof in my professor's notes goes like this:
"In analogy to what was done in the proof of Proposition 3.33, we consider the extension of $\varphi : K \hookrightarrow \overline{K}$ to a map from $K[x]$ to $\overline{K}$:
\begin{equation}
\tilde{\varphi} : K[x] \longrightarrow \overline{K} : x \longmapsto \beta, p(x) \longmapsto \left(\varphi(p(x))\right)(\beta)
\quad \text{with} \quad \tilde{\varphi}|_K = \varphi
\end{equation}
where $\varphi(p(x))$ means the polynomial with the coefficients mapped via $\varphi$.
For such a homomorphism, we have $(\mu_\alpha(x)) \subseteq \ker(\varphi)$ ($(\mu_\alpha(x))$ being the minimum degree and monic polynomial of $\alpha$), hence $\varphi(\mu_\alpha(x)) = 0$, so we apply $\varphi$ to the coefficients of $\mu_\alpha(x)$ (previously left fixed because we used the identity) and we evaluate the new polynomial in $\beta$, therefore $\beta$ must be a root of $\varphi(\mu_\alpha(x))$, so the extensions of $\varphi$ to $K(\alpha)$ are as many as the distinct roots of $\varphi(\mu_\alpha(x))$ in $\overline{K}$."
This part is clear to me and I posted it to give some context about the answer I'm going to ask. The proof goes on like this:
"Since $\mu_\alpha(x)$ is irreducible by definition, then $\varphi(\mu_\alpha(x))$ is also irreducible, moreover, $\deg \varphi(\mu_\alpha(x)) = \deg \mu_\alpha(x)$ (since the homomorphism is injective), therefore, since the field is perfect, the number of distinct roots of $\varphi(\mu_\alpha(x))$ is equal to its degree, and hence to that of $\mu_\alpha(x)$."
Now, I cannot quite understand the bold part of the proof. First of all what does that mean for $\varphi(\mu_\alpha(x))$ to be irreducible? In which field is that polynomial irreducible (if it were irreducible in the closure, the following would make no sense given that only polynomials of degree 1 or less are irreducible in the closure). And then what about the fact the field is perfect? Again I don't understand what the field involved is. After this there's also an example in which it consider the homomorphism from $K = \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{2}
)$ to $\overline{K}$ sending $\sqrt[3]{2}$ to $\sqrt[3]{2} \zeta_3$ and acting like the identity on $\mathbb{Q}$: by this it's clear that the field in which $\varphi(\mu_\alpha(x))$ is irreducible is not $K$, am I right? What am I missing? Thank you for the answers.
Edit: I think the field involved is the image through $\varphi$ of $K$, and it should share the same properties of K (such as being perfect (?)). Am I wrong? Could you provide more details?

I think you need to add the hypothesis that $\alpha$ is separable over $K$ in order that the theorem stated is correct.

Well, while continuing reading I found that you assumed $K$ being perfect, which you dropped in the statement of the theorem.

Yes, thank you for the edits. Anyhow could you help me about the question?

More generally speaking, let $\varphi: k\to K$ be a field monomorphism. This gives a monomorphism $k[x]\to K[x]$, which I abuse notation and call it $\varphi$ also. Then $f(x)\in k[x]$ is irreducible over $k$ $\Leftrightarrow$ $\varphi(f(x))$ is irreducible over $\varphi(k)$. Proof for $(\Rightarrow)$: Assume conversely $\varphi(f(x))=a(x)b(x)$ where $a(x), b(x)\in\varphi(k)[x]$, then $f(x)=\varphi^{-1}(a(x))\varphi^{-1}(b(x))$. Proof for $(\Leftarrow)$ is similar and I omit it. (But please do not hesitate to ask if you can't show $(\Leftarrow)$ after some thought.)

Intuitively speaking, polynomial rings over $k$ and $\varphi(k)$ are isomorphic, and the isomorphism map $\varphi$ preserves almost all "algebraic" properties.

Yes, thank you. Both implications are clear to me, I just wanted to be sure the irreducibility of the polynomial $\varphi(\mu_{\alpha} (x))$ was to be interpreted over $\varphi(K) [x]$.
